# Using btoa both in Jasmine and browser

Tags: javascript, browserify

I'm using **btoa** function in a JavaScript file. It should run both in unit tests using Jasmine and in the browser.
Since **btoa** is not available in node, I imported the npm package [btoa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/btoa).
I'm using browserify and since this function is already defined in the browser, I don't want to bundle it with my JS.
I import it using:

```
var btoa = require("btoa");
```

and call it:

```
var x = btoa(plainText);
```

The issue is that when I use browserify, the function gets bundled with the output js. I tried the **-i btoa** flag but the result was I'm getting "btoa is not a function" error in the browser.
How to import this module only when running unit tests?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using "btoa-lite" package instead of btoa package.
"btoa-lite" defines btoa-node.js which is used in node (and Jasmine unit tests) btoa-browser.js which browserify references when it bundles JavaScript dependencies. btoa-browser.js just forwards the call to btoa function implemented in the browser.
The same for "atob-lite" package.